# Support dynamic content (not on the filesystem) using ASP.NET MVC bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, squishit

I have been using SquishIt to bundle and minify css and javascript. Now, I have to move to MVC bundles and replace SquishIt. SquishIt provides a way to to feed in dynamic content at runtime so that I can load things like LESS variables from a database.

Here's how I do in SquishIt when I need to feed in javascript string:

```
  .AddString("$(function() { alert('Need Support for dynamic content'); });")
```

Currently it looks like the only way I can bundle content in ASP.NET MVC bundles is if there is an actual file on the file system. Is there a way to read the content from database and feed to MVC bundle?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out on this?

Comment: Yes, I did. Created a new bundle transform that takes in a string. Something like,

    `public class DynamicCSSContent : IBundleTransform
    {
        string content;

        public DynamicCSSContent(string content)
        {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
        {
            response.Content = content;
            response.ContentType = "text/css";
        }
    }`
However, had to create a separate method to merge two bundles to add the dynamic string to an existing bundle/css file